# Using VBScript to read inbox from Outlook Web Access

Tags: vbscript, outlook-web-app

I have an email account, which is accessed via OWA.

I would like to set-up a small VBScript app to periodically check the inbox for new unread messages.

I can already access the OWA account manually but would like to automate this.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the MAPI function and call (outlook.application) to check the inbox. and read all the inbox messages or even download attachments, mark mail items unread. Create an exe. and call it at startup or schedule a server job.